# Space complexity- various cases functions involving arrays

Tags: arrays, algorithm, big-o, computer-science, space-complexity

here i have written some different cases of functions that have array as input i need help to determine if reasoning behind my answers is correct (i have put question marks on the cases im having difficulty with)

**case 1:**

```
algo(arr[],n){
  //does nothing
}
```

Space = (0) + 0 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 0 = O(1)

(reason: storage allocated for inputs havent been worked on and no temporary storage declared inside the function)

**case 2:**

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i;
}
```

Space = (0) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: storage allocated for inputs havent been worked on and 1 temporary storage for variable i is needed)

**case 3:**

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i;
   for(i=0; i<n ; i++){
    //does nothing
   }
}
```

Space = (1) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: storage for variable n is being worked on and 1 temp storage needed for variable i is needed)

**case 4:**

where arr[] is an array of size L where L > n

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    arr[i] = i;
   }
}
```

Space = (1 + n) + 1 = O(n)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: 1 storage for variable n and n storages for arr[0]....arr[n-1] is being worked on and 1 temp storage for variable i is needed)

**case 5**:??

where arr[] is an array of size L where L > n

```
algo(arr[],n){               
   arr[n]=n;
}
```

Space = (1 + 1) + 0 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 0 = O(1)

(reason: 1 storage for variable n is being worked on and only 1 storage will always be worked on in arr[] regardless of the value of n, no temporary storage was declared)

**case 6**:??

where arr[] is an array of size L where L > i

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i = 1;
  arr[i]=i;
}
```

Space = (1) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: only 1 storage will always be worked on in arr[] which is always in arr[i] and 1 temp storage needed for i)

**case 7**:??

where arr[] is an array of size L where L > n

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    // does nothing
   }
   arr[n] = n;

}
```

Space = (1 + 1) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: 1 storage for variable n is being worked on and only 1 storage will always be worked on in arr[] regardless of the value of n, 1 temporary storage was declared for variable i)

**case 8**:??

where arr[] is an array of size L where L > i

```
algo(arr[],n){
   int i;
   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
    // does nothing
   }
   i = 1;
   arr[i] = i;

}
```

Space = (1 + 1) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: only 1 storage will always be worked on in arr[] which is always in arr[i], 1 storage for variable n being worked on,  and 1 temp storage needed for variable i)

**case 9**:

where arr1[] is an array of size m

```
algo(arr1[],n){
   int arr2[n];
}
```

Space = (1) + n = O(n)

Auxiliary Space = n = O(n)

(reason: 1 storage for variable n being worked on, n temporary storage needed for arr2[])

**case 10**:??

where arr1[] is an array of size L

```
algo(arr1[],n){
   int m=1;
   int arr2[m];
}
```

Space = (0) + 1 + m = O(m)

Auxiliary Space = 1 + m = O(m)

(reason: 1 temporary storage needed for variable m and m temporary storage needed for arr2[])

or

Space = (0) + 1 + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 + 1 = O(1)

(reason: 1 temporary storage needed for variable m and since m is a constant the space required for arr2[] always going to be some constant c)

**case 11**:??

```
algo(arr1[],n){
   int i;
   int m=10;
   int arr2[m];

   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
     arr2[i]= i;
   }   

}
```

Space = (0) + 1 + 1 + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 + 1 + 1 = O(1)

(reason: 1 temporary storage needed for variable m, 1 temp storage for variable i and since m is a constant the space required for arr2[] always going to be some constant c)

**case 12**:

where arr1[] is an array of size L where L > n and then arr2[] is an array of size K where K > m

```
algo(arr1[],n, arr2[], m){
   int i;

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     arr1[i]= i;
   }   

   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
     arr2[i]= i;
   }   

}
```

Space = (1 + n + 1 + m) + 1 = O(n + m)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: 2 storage for var n and m being worked on, n storage for arr1, m storage for arr2 and 1 storage needed for var i)

**case 13**:??

where arr1[] is an array of size L and L > n

```
algo(arr1[],n){
   int i;
   int m=10;
   int arr2[m];

   for(i=0;i<n;i++){
     arr1[i]= i;
   }   

   for(i=0;i<m;i++){
     arr2[i]= i;
   }   

}
```

Space = (1 + n) + 1 + 1 + 1 = O(n)

Auxiliary Space = 1 + 1 + 1 = O(1)

(reason: 2 spaces needed for variable i and m, constant m space needed for arr2, 1 space being worked on for var n and n space being worked on for arr1)

**case 14**:

```
 algo(arr1[],n){

   int arr2[10];

 }
```

Space = (0) + 1 = O(1)

Auxiliary Space = 1 = O(1)

(reason: 10 spaces is always required to declare arr2 whenever the function is called)

Comment: In case 4 you already have array declared so it's O(L) and assigning new variables to its locations wont change its size further. Thus Auxiliary space is O(1)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's too broad, since it's essentially 14 distinct questions, and we're here to provide answers, not verify them.

Comment: We don't really have a good canonical question about space complexity (that I've seen), so maybe that would be useful, but this would require quite a bit of editing to get there (but no, I don't really know what that edit should look like).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ok, instead of addressing each case one by one, I will try to help you understand space complexity which will probably answer all your doubts.

> Space complexity of a method is defined as how much amount of extra
>   space your method uses, as the input grows, to run an algorithm of your
>   choice.

```
algo(arr[],n){
}

algo(arr1[],n, arr2[], m){
}
```

In the above method definitions-

- If I only operate on parameter variables along with some extra variables like-

  > int a=1,b=10,c=99;
  >
  > int[] new_array = new int[1000];
  >
  > int m=1;   int[] arr = new int[m];

  All these will still be considered as `O(1)` space complexity. As you can see, the 
  number of variables and size of them doesn't change regardless of how big my input is.
- If I declare additional variables which grows with input like-

  > int[] sum = new int[n];
  >
  > int[][] sum = new int[n][n];
  >
  > int[][] sum = new int[n][m];

  As you can notice, the size of my array depends on `n` which was the parameter that was 
  passed to the method. Here, if my input array size happens to be `1000000000`, my 
  method will also consume `1000000000` making it `O(n)` in space.

  > int[] sum = new int[n]; takes `O(n)` space since size depends on `n`
  >
  > int[][] sum = new int[n][n]; takes O(n<sup>2</sup>) space since it has `n` rows and 
  >   `n` columns.
  >
  > int[][] sum = new int[n][m]; takes `O(n*m)` space since it has `n` rows and `m` 
  >   columns.

> ```
> int[][] arr = new int[n][];
>
> for(int i=0;i<n;++i){
>    arr[i] = new int[i+1];
> }
> ```

The above code snippet does the following-

- Declares an array having `n` rows.
- Assigns size/number of columns to each row. If size of columns varies for each row, it is known as **jagged array**.
- Example-

  1<sup>st</sup> row - 1 column.

  2<sup>nd</sup> row - 2 columns.

  3<sup>rd</sup> row - 3 columns.

  4<sup>th</sup> row - 4 columns.

  and so on and so forth till

  n<sup>th</sup> row - `n` columns.

The space complexity of the above code is O(n<sup>2</sup>). Reason is because, in asymptotic notation, we care more about the `worst case` scenario. Here,regardless of other rows,for the n<sup>th</sup> row, we are having `n` columns and this grows with input as well.

I hope this made you clear about space complexity.

Comment: thank you for explaining, really help me through my algorithms class

Answer (score 0):

If you are using an already allocated array say for INTEGERS, it will have the size; sizeof(int)*n, n here being the size of the said array. If you pass it by value you will have a local copy of it , if you pass it by reference or with a pointer you won't copy it. Putting elements inside array or modifying its elements wont change its already allocated size you will have the same space complexity.

Declaring a fix amount of variables will also not change the space complexity, be careful here I am saying space complexity not the actual space. So to answer your questions all in once;

- If you modify the elements of an already existing array you wont change the space complexity ( even if its empty , it already will have allocated `sizeof(elementtype)* element_number` space).
- If you had `O(n)` space before and then you create a new array with `m` elements you will need extra space and you space complexity will be `O(m+n)` (whichever is bigger).
- Fixed amount of variables won't effect the space complexity and will only effect the total space you used.